# TimeShift not backing up to USB flash drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, backup

Every time I attempt a backup with TimeShift to a USB flash drive, I get a message that there is no partition on it. I used Gparted, but apparently it was not successful in creating a partition. However, when I do a TimeShift backup of my Ubuntu Mate with the Cupertino desktop, it does backup; but to my hard drive. That may sound good and it did help on one ocassion to restore my sytem, but I want to do a full backup to my flash drive.  Any thoughts? I've looked online for numerous suggestions on how to format the drive and put the partion on it, but apparently only the formating worked.

Comment: What output do you get from lsblk when the flash drive is connected? Can you save a simple text file to the drive? Is the drive encrypted in any way? When you used GParted did you apply the changes that you made to the drive? GParted can look like it’s done something when you still need to apply the changes.

Comment: The Ubuntu Mate recogizes the flash drive which has nothing on it since it is new.  Not encrypted.  I applied Gparted.  Still frustrated.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Might be able to help if you answer my first two questions. lsblk is a command you type into the terminal. It will show the storage devices connected to your computer, any partitions on them and where they are mounted if at all. Depending on what this shows there are a range of different courses to take. Just so that you are aware a flash drive is not the most reliable device on which to store important data. I’d recommend an external hard drive of some sort for that.

Comment: I’ve just checked this out on my own machine and noticed that the snapshot location has to be a Linux filesystem. Have you formatted the filesystem? Frequently flash drives are some variation of FAT which will not work. Format the partition as ext4 and you should be good to go. I think TimeShift will mount the partition for you but you might need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Since I posted the question, about midnight I discovered the following site:
https://ubuntu-mate.org/faq/usb-image/

It didn’t really answer my question, but I followed the section called, Ubuntu/Ubuntu MATE.  Even though I put Ubuntu Mate on the flash drive, I was then able to do a full TimeShift backup on that flash drive.  I don’t know why that happened (I am basically a newbie, somewhat intermediate user of Linux); but I am happy I got the backup.

Thank all of you for your assistance.  Linux does have a wonderful and rapid reply Community.

Comment: The reason that worked was probably because when you copied Mate to the flash drive it created a Linux filesystem first

Comment: Thank you for  your insight.